# Is it More Performant to Pass Props From Parent Component Or Listen to State Change In Flux Store?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Let's say I have the following parent -> child relationship(s) inside of a react component:

```
<parentComponent>
    <childComponent>
        <grandChildComponent>
            <greatGrandChildComponent></greatGrandChildComponent>
                ...
                  ...
                     ... // And so on
        </grandChildComponent>
</parentComponent>
```

Assuming I'm getting data from a Flux store, is it more performant to have `<parentComponent>` get its state from / listen for changes on the Flux store and then pass the relevant data down to its children as `props` or is it more performant to have each `<..child>` component listen to the store directly for any updates to its state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance would likely depend on your specific program. Is there a reason youre concerned with performance between these two practices? I must imagine its an extremely minimal difference.

that being said, idiomatic react greatly favors stateful components housing stateless components. unless theres a good reason for a child component to manage itself (that is manage its own state and not let its parent manage it), you should be composing your site with as few stateful components as possible that contain many stateless children.

tl;dr pass in props from your parent

Comment: My main concern revolves around the amount of listeners on the store. I assume that the more components that listen to a store, the less performant the page becomes?